ranking in Power BI with max date considered if multiple codes for an id and date
stuck on ranking this in power bi --
I have a bunch of codes that needs to get ranked so I can filter in final report. I can't use Asc/Desc order because the rank for each code doesn't align if I use that. Also need to consider the latest date and use that if multiple code for same id is present
ex:

`rank` order
`c1 - 6`
`c5 - 5`
`c4 - 4`
`c7 - 3`
`c9 - 2`
`c11 -1`

results 

| `id`     |` code `|| ` Date `      |`rank` (what I want to see)    
| -------- | -------|| --------      --------   
| 1234     | c5     || 1/2/12 12:06  | 1       
| 1234     | c1     || 1/2/12 12:03  | 2 
  
| 2345     | c4     || 2/3/12 12:04  | 2 
| 2345     | c4     || 2/3/12 12:06  | 1

| 3456     | c7     || 2/3/12 12:00  | 1 
| 3456     | c4     || 2/3/12 12:04  | 2
| 3456     | c1     || 2/3/12 12:04  | 3 
  
| 4567     | c9     || 9/01/12 12:30 | 3       
| 4567     | c11    || 9/01/12 12:32 | 2
| 4567     | c11    || 9/01/12 12:34 | 1
| 4567     | c1     || 9/01/12 12:34 | 4

| 5667     | c5     || 1/2/12 12:06  | 1

